# Weird behavior of .toggleClass() method

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two div elements (cards) that I want to perform flip effect (using css3). Problem is when user clicks on div element (i. e. card) all cards are flipped. I want to flip only div (card) that is clicked, not all divs. Can someone told me where is problem?

Here is jsFiddle demo:

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wvveY/58/)

Here is code that is used:

HTML:

```
<div class="flip-container">
    <div class="flipper" id="flipper">
        <div class="front"> 
        </div>
    <div class="back">
            <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/reclusekc/kulo/96/Skull-1-icon.png">
        </div>
        <div class="front"> 
        </div>
    <div class="back">
            <img src="http://img9.uploadhouse.com/fileuploads/17699/176992615db99bb0fd652a2e6041388b2839a634.png">
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
/*Jquery is incuded */
$(".flipper").click(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    document.getElementById(id).classList.toggle('flipped');
});
```

CSS:

```
/* entire container, keeps perspective */
.flip-container{
/*perspective*/
-webkit-perspective:1000;
   -moz-perspective:1000;
    -ms-perspective:1000;
     -o-perspective:1000;
        perspective:1000;
    display: table;
        margin: 0px auto;
    width: auto;
}
/* flip the pane when hovered */
    .flipped {
/*transform*/
-webkit-transform:rotateY(180deg);
   -moz-transform:rotateY(180deg);
    -ms-transform:rotateY(180deg);
     -o-transform:rotateY(180deg);
        transform:rotateY(180deg);
}
.front, .back{
 float: left;
    width: 100px;
    height: 120px;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 4px solid #EE872A;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
        z-index:2;
  background: #B1B1B1;
    /*backface-visibility*/
-webkit-backface-visibility:hidden;
   -moz-backface-visibility:hidden;
    -ms-backface-visibility:hidden;
     -o-backface-visibility:hidden;
        backface-visibility:hidden;

}
/* flip speed goes here */
.flipper {
/*transition*/
-webkit-transition:0.6s;
   -moz-transition:0.6s;
     -o-transition:0.6s;
        transition:0.6s;
/*transform-style*/
-webkit-transform-style:preserve-3d;
   -moz-transform-style:preserve-3d;
    -ms-transform-style:preserve-3d;
     -o-transform-style:preserve-3d;
        transform-style:preserve-3d;
position:relative;
}
/* hide back of pane during swap */
/* front pane, placed above back */
/* back, initially hidden pane */
.back{
/*transform*/
-webkit-transform:rotateY(180deg);
   -moz-transform:rotateY(180deg);
    -ms-transform:rotateY(180deg);
     -o-transform:rotateY(180deg);
        transform:rotateY(180deg);
    z-index:3;
}
```

Comment: Where's `.toggleClass()`?

Comment: if using jquery, why not use this : `$(id).toggleClass('flipped');` instead of this: `document.getElementById(id).classList.toggle('flipped');` ?

Comment: Also, you have only one element with the class `flipper` which contains both cards so of course clicking on it flips the entire view. Puth both cards in separate containers.

Comment: @blurfus you have a vaild point. I will modify my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick http://jsfiddle.net/wvveY/61/

```
<div class="flip-container">
    <div class="flipper">
        <div class="front"></div>
        <div class="back">
            <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/reclusekc/kulo/96/Skull-1-icon.png">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="flipper">
        <div class="front"></div>
        <div class="back">
            <img src="http://img9.uploadhouse.com/fileuploads/17699/176992615db99bb0fd652a2e6041388b2839a634.png">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


$(".flipper").click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('flipped');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try using this in your JS

```
$(".flipper").click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('flipped');
});
```

**Update**
and your HTML as follows:

```
<div class="flipper">
    <div class="front"> 
    </div>
    <div class="back">
       <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/reclusekc/kulo/96/Skull-1-icon.png">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="flipper">
    <div class="front"> 
    </div>
    <div class="back">
        <img src="http://img9.uploadhouse.com/fileuploads/17699/176992615db99bb0fd652a2e6041388b2839a634.png">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think that problem is not there. Thank you for answer btw. I will try your solution

Comment: you will need to adjust your 'flipper' values (right now they are one on top of the other and flipping like a page)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want something like that http://jsfiddle.net/wvveY/67/

You need to separate your cards to like this:

```
<div class="flip-container">
    <div class="flipper" >
        <div class="front"> 
        </div>
    <div class="back">
            <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/reclusekc/kulo/96/Skull-1-icon.png">
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="flipper" >
        <div class="front"> 
        </div>
    <div class="back">
            <img src="http://img9.uploadhouse.com/fileuploads/17699/176992615db99bb0fd652a2e6041388b2839a634.png">
        </div>
```